# Trace tauto, finish

Tags: debugging, math, theorem-proving, lean

Is there a way to trace `tauto`, `finish` tactics (or others that don't fall into simp) in Lean?
E.g.

```
example (P Q : Prop) : a → b ↔ ¬a ∨ b := by tauto
```

I'd like to see the neccesary rewritings or theorems that are applied to the terms to prove the goal, in order to use them explicitly in more complex situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import tactic

theorem foo (a b : Prop) : a → b ↔ ¬a ∨ b := by tauto!

#print foo
```

shows you the term that the tactic created. But high-powered tactics are not designed to produce readable terms, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the general purpose `show_term { tauto }` which will print a message showing the term that `tauto` (or whatever tactic you used) constructed.

As Kevin points out above, some tactics produce inscrutable and/or enormous terms.